# Possible to update CSS files automatically everyday?

Tags: java, html, css, web, frontend

I am building a website through a static site generator called Hugo, and I was wondering if there is a way using which my CSS files could get updated at a given time every single day. I want to be able to make a particular title whose font updates every day on my site. Is there a way to automate the entire process, given that I also have to push my website folder through git in order to deploy/update my site. Thank you very much.

Assume that I can download all the font files I need to periodically update beforehand.

Comment: If you are deploying with git, you could use a post-receive hook to build the website.

Comment: Scheduled events like you are talking about are usually kicked off by a `cron` job on unix, or windows services on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hugo is a static site generator, and there is no backend to Hugo sites, you can't change the font internally without changing the source code. However, you can call an API that returns a font for a given day. For example, if you have an API that returns a font depending on the day you call that API, your static site can get the font from there. Otherwise, the code would have to be redeployed with a new font every day.